# convert string to other type in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

Hi everyone I have a simple problem but I don't find the solution, I have a function that returns something like that

```
[[4, 'adr', 0, 0, 1, '2016-04-05T13:00:01'], [115, 'adr', 0, 0, 1, '2016-04-05T14:00:01'], [226, 'adr', 0, 0, 1, '2016-04-05T15:00:01'], [337, 'adr', 0, 0, 1, '2016-04-05T16:00:01']]
```

when I check de type of this variable `type(data)`say that is a string `<type 'str'>`
I want to create a loop to get each element like this

item 1 `[4, 'adr', 0, 0, 1, '2016-04-05T13:00:01']`

item 2 `[115, 'adr', 0, 0, 1, '2016-04-05T14:00:01']`

I try to convert the string in a list, a tuple... but nothing work, any idea how to change the string to any type that I can do a loop and get the items

when I try to convert in a tuple or string I have this result

```
('[', '[', '4', ',', ' ', "'", 'a', 'd', 'r', "'", ',', ' ', '0', ',', ' ', '0', ',', ' ', '1', ',', ' ', "'", '2', '0', '1', '6', '-', '0', '4', '-', '0', '5', 'T', '1', '3', ':', '0', '0', ':', '0', '1', "'", ']', ',', ' ', '[', '1', '1', '5', ',', ' ', "'", 'a', 'd', 'r', "'", ',', ' ', '0', ',', ' ', '0', ',', ' ', '1', ',', ' ', "'", '2', '0', '1', '6', '-', '0', '4', '-', '0', '5', 'T', '1', '4', ':', '0', '0', ':', '0', '1', "'", ']', ',', ' ', '[', '2', '2', '6', ',', ' ', "'", 'a', 'd', 'r', "'", ',', ' ', '0', ',', ' ', '0', ',', ' ', '1', ',', ' ', "'", '2', '0', '1', '6', '-', '0', '4', '-', '0', '5', 'T', '1', '5', ':', '0', '0', ':', '0', '1', "'", ']', ',', ' ', '[', '3', '3', '7', ',', ' ', "'", 'a', 'd', 'r', "'", ',', ' ', '0', ',', ' ', '0', ',', ' ', '1', ',', ' ', "'", '2', '0', '1', '6', '-', '0', '4', '-', '0', '5', 'T', '1', '6', ':', '0', '0', ':', '0', '1', "'", ']', ']')
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert string representation of list to list in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894269/convert-string-representation-of-list-to-list-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi everyone I finally resolve the problem like this

```
data = {}
data = {'names': []}
for item in project_name:
  data['names'].append(item)
  data.update({item: {}})
  jobs_running = []
  jobs_pending = []
  for row in all_rows:
    if (str(item) == row[1]):
      parsed_t = dp.parse(str(row[5]))
      t_in_seconds = parsed_t.strftime('%s')

      jobs_running.append([ (t_in_seconds), (row[3]) ])
      jobs_pending.append([ (t_in_seconds), (row[4]) ])
      data[item].update({'jobs_running': jobs_running})
      data[item].update({'jobs_pending': jobs_pending})
```

So my data structure is like this [see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aPANZ.png)

Answer (score 3):

You might consider to use [literal_eval from ast](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) module.

```
In [8]: from ast import literal_eval

In [9]: a = "[[4, 'adr', 0, 0, 1, '2016-04-05T13:00:01'], [115, 'adr', 0, 0, 1, '2016-04-05T14:00:01'], [226, 'adr', 0, 0, 1, '2016-04-05T15:00:01'], [337, 'adr', 0, 0, 1, '2016-04-05T16:00:01']]"

In [10]: type(a)
Out[10]: str

In [11]: b = literal_eval(a)

In [12]: type(b)
Out[12]: list

In [13]: b
Out[13]: 
[[4, 'adr', 0, 0, 1, '2016-04-05T13:00:01'],
 [115, 'adr', 0, 0, 1, '2016-04-05T14:00:01'],
 [226, 'adr', 0, 0, 1, '2016-04-05T15:00:01'],
 [337, 'adr', 0, 0, 1, '2016-04-05T16:00:01']]
```

Then you have a proper list and can easily iterate on it to get it's element.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest, and most dangerous, solution would be to do

```
eval( data )
```

Dangerous because you have to trust there is nothing malicious in that data.

You could write a regex to verify that the string/data is properly formatted; not knowing what that format is, I can't help with that.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [ast.literal_eval](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal%5Feval):

```
import ast
myteststr = "[[4, 'adr', 0, 0, 1, '2016-04-05T13:00:01'], [115, 'adr', 0, 0, 1, '2016-04-05T14:00:01'], [226, 'adr', 0, 0, 1, '2016-04-05T15:00:01'], [337, 'adr', 0, 0, 1, '2016-04-05T16:00:01']]"
pyobj = ast.literal_eval(myteststr)
print(pyobj)
```